# python write to excel overwrite cell

Tags: python, list, for-loop, debugging, export-to-excel

I have one list with country names and one list with strings containing transaction data. The transaction data should contain a country - if not, it should give N/A. How can I loop the transactions data into column 1 and the country name into column 2? This is my attempt so far, but it returns that I overwrite cells.

FYI: the length of transaction data < the length of country names.

```
for i in range(len(transactions)):
    ws.write(i, 0, transactions[i])                   #Paste transaction data into column 0
    for country in countries:
        if country in transactions[i]:
            ws.write(i,1,country)
        else:
            ws.write(i,1,"N/A")
```

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use pandas instead of writing to the file directly. If I understood your problem correctly, then something like this should work:

```
excel_table = {
    "transactions": [],
    "countries": [],
}

for i, transaction in enumerate(transactions): 
    for country in countries:
        if country in transaction: 
            excel_table["transactions"].append(transaction)
            excel_table["countries"].append(country)
            break
    else: 
        excel_table["transactions"].append(transaction)
        excel_table["countries"].append("N/A")

df = pd.DataFrame(excel_table)

df.to_excel("path.xlsx")
```

Also, remember to install the necessary dependencies:

```
pip install pandas
pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Im getting invalid syntax at the excel_table = [.... at the beginning. To be more precise, its a job computer, hence I only have the packages that come with Anaconda (panda and openpyxl is included) - but nothing outside of this.

Comment: To be precise about the data, I have a list with transactions, for each i in transaction, there are customer information followed up by an address and a country. I wish to extract this country using a country list.

Comment: Now its fixed. I meant to use a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks :) It seems like it pastes too many combinations as the sheet size is too large to be created. I have about 1300 transactions and 7000 countries (various spelling of countries etc with special characters as the transactions are hand-written and because # indicates a new line in the system we use, hence I have e.g. USA, U#SA, US#A,....

Comment: It seems weird that the length of the excel is longer than the number of transactions

Comment: Mmmm, when I tested it i got the right size. Maybe you forgot to add the break?